# Email Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, email

I'm having a problem with my script,

it's a notifier that emails me on a specific set of time then includes a statement if the file exceeds 100kb

Here is my script, how can i configure this so that it will send me the notification?

```
#!/bin/bash

file="afile"
maxsize=100

while true; do

        actualsize=$(du -k "$file" | cut -f1)

        if [ $actualsize -ge $maxsize ]
        then
                echo size is over $maxsize kilobytes
                subject="size exceed on file $file"
                emailAddr="emvpacifico@gmail.com"
                emailCmd="mail -s \"$exceedfile\" \"$emvpacifico\""
        (echo ""; echo "date: $(date)";) | eval mail -s "$exceedfile" \"$emvpacifico@gmail.com\"
                exit
        else
                echo size is under $maxsize kilobytes
        fi

        sleep 60
done
```

Comment: I was going to fix the formatting, but it seems I can’t edit it. Good luck!

Comment: Are the lines starting with `emailCmd` and `(echo ""` supposed to be the same logical line, or are they separate statements?

Comment: drop `eval` and remove the backslashes from the recipient address.

Comment: paste your code into https://shellcheck.net to fix the other issues.

Answer (score 1):

A quick rewrite, with comments inline:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="afile"
maxsize=100

while true; do
   # Use `stat`, the tool for getting file metadata, rather than `du`
   # and chewing on its output.  It gives size in bytes, so divide by
   # 1024 for kilobytes.
   actualsize=$(($(stat --printf="%s" "$file")/1024))
      if [[ $actualsize -ge $maxsize ]]; then
         echo "size is over $maxsize kilobytes"
         subject="size exceed on file $file"
         emailAddr="somebody@example.com"
         # In almost all cases, if you are using `eval`, either
         # something has gone very wrong, or you are doing a thing in
         # a _very_ suboptimal way.
         echo "Date: $(date)" | mail -s "$subject" "$emailAddr"
      else
         echo "size is under $maxsize kilobytes"
      fi
   sleep 60
done
```

Also, I would suggest rather than running a script with an infinite loop, altering the script to run only once, and scheduling it to run using a `cron` table entry.